# Let $R$ be a commutative ring of even order say $2^km$, where 2 does not devides m. Show that $m^n.1\neq 0$ in $R$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: ring-theory

If possible let $m^n.1=0$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. then $O(1)$ divides $m^n$ as an abelian group $(R,+)$. It implies that $O(1)/m$ and hence $m.1=0$. Now I am not able to show a contradiction that $m.1\neq 0$.

Comment: What's the dot in $m^n.1$? And $O(1)$?

Comment: m.1 means (1+1+1+...+1), m times.

Comment: In the problem $1$ is the unity element of $R$.

Comment: $O(1)$ means order of $1$ in $(R,+)$.

Comment: $O(1)$ dividing $m^n$ doesn't imply $O(1)=m$. It only implies $O(1)\mid m$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. its actually $O(1)|m$.

Comment: I don't see how you conclude that $O(1)\mid m$. $9\mid 3^2$ but $9\nmid 3.$

Comment: @GreginGre Since $(R, +)$ is a group of order $2^km$, by Lagrange's theorem $O(1)$ must divide $2^km$. And if $O(1)$ also divides $m^n$, it is odd, and must therefore divide $m$.

Answer (score 0):

If $m\cdot 1=0$, then  $m\cdot a=0$ for any $a\in R$, since we have $$m\cdot a=a+\cdots +a=(1+\cdots +1)a=(m\cdot 1)a=0a=0.$$
Now, it implies that $O(a)\mid m$ for all $a\in R,$ so any $a\in R$ has odd order.

But this is not possible: since $R$ has even order, by Cauchy's theorem, $R$ has an element of order $2.$